# I'm trying to make a wordle clone, but can't get a square to turn green if the letter inside of it matches a letter in the word. How can I do this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, styles, replit

```
let body = document.querySelector("body")
let container = document.querySelector("#container")
//Accessing HTML Elements




let inputArr = []
for (let rowCount = 0; rowCount < 6; rowCount++) {
  let row = []
  inputArr.push(row)

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let space = document.createElement("input");
    container.appendChild(space)
    row.push(space); 
    space.classList.add("square")
  }
}
//for loops that make the grid of squares for the wordle, and store them inside a 2d array


let wordSet = ["panic", "knobs", "swain", "dupes", "venom", "great", "carom", "soare"]

let num = Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
let word = wordSet[num]
console.log(word)

for (let rowVal = 0; rowVal < 6; rowVal++) {
  for (let col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
    if (inputArr[rowVal][col].value instanceof String && inputArr[rowVal][col] == word[col]) {
      
        inputArr[rowVal][col].style.backgroundColor = "green"
      
    }
    
  }
}
```

The last part of the code essentially checks whether the input value of a square is equal to a string, and if the value matches a letter in the word. If these two things are true, then the square is supposed to change to green.

Is there another way to achieve the task of checking whether a letter is correct or not that works?

Comment: You've made a good start, but there are few problems. Your word checker only runs once and stops.  You will need to place it inside an event handler to have it constantly check the input as the user types. See: [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and you want to add it to your container.

Comment: I added an enter button to the wordle clone, and created a different for loop to react to a click on that enter button, but things still don't seem to be working properly. Is their something else I can do to make it function the right way? Here's my code:

Comment: oh wait I guess it's too long to add